# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on music app which has songs queue contains duplicate songs (as per user's requirement to repeat the song) with different state , one of them could be in playing state or others not([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdeIQ.jpg)).

I have set `setHasStableIds(true)` to the adapter and implemented `getItemId` as below:

```
 override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return dataset[position].songId.hashCode().toLong()
}
```

Also I have tried extending `Song` as below , I don't think it's good idea ?

```
data class QueueSong(private val song: Song) : Song(song) {
   val queueId: Int = hashCode()
}
```

Anyone please help with this, thank you !!

Comment: Just keep id counter separated frim songs and increment it after each added? Ir something like that

Comment: I think, having counter will lose the state when recycling..what i want to return unique id on getItemId() for each song even if there are duplicates so that I can maintain the state.

Comment: So make it persistent (ie stored in shared prefs). I did not say this counter must be coupled with the list or adapter. I just proposed using data independent way of assigning IDs.

Comment: Something like this , you are suggesting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302318/how-to-generate-unique-ids-for-recyclerview-in-case-of-2-ids-per-item#:~:text=The%20easy%20way%20to%20overcome,Pair%22%20class%20in%20this%20case.

Answer (score 0):

1. `getItemId()` must return a unique result for each item if `setHasStableIds(true)`.
2. If two objects are equal according to the `equals()` method, then calling the `hashCode()` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Duplicate songs have the same `songId`, so your implementation of `getItemId()` will return the same result.

`data class QueueSong` and `val queueId: Int = hashCode()` won't work either because Kotlin will automatically generate `equals()` and `hashCode()` for that class. Duplicate `QueueSong` with the same `Song` will produce the same hash code.

You should generate a unique `queueId` using something like `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` to ensure they have unique hash code.

Comment: getItemId return long value, are you sure hashcode of  ``UUID.randomUUID().toString()``  will be unique for even duplicate songs ?